# Bootstrap Affix "Back to Top" Link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Alright, I'm having trouble understanding the [Bootstrap Affix component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). My goal is to have a "Back to Top" link appear at the bottom left of the screen (in the margin) if/when the page is scrolled below the top of the content. My page has a NavBar fixed to the top and a container for the body. Below is the general idea of where I'm at but I've also [setup a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Panman8201/MKZrm/1/) that demonstrates my setup. I'm also not a pro at positioning so that is part of my issue too.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">...</div>
<div class="content-container" id="top">
    <p>Content that is longer than the viewport..</p>
    <span id="top-link" data-spy="affix">
        <a href="#top" class="well well-sm">Back to Top</a>
    </span>
</div>

<style>
    .navbar-fixed-top + .content-container {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
    .content-container {
        margin: 0 125px;
    }
    #top-link.affix {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://markgoodyear.com/labs/scrollup/?theme=tab. Super easy to use

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Justin but I was trying to do it the "Bootstrap way" due to other needs not shown in this post/question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Now that I understand the Affix component better, I have come up with the solution. After specifying a top offset and adjusting the CSS, it's working nicely. The link will scroll into view and then "pin" to the bottom. For pages which do not have a scroll bar, the link is never enabled. I've updated the [JS Fiddle (here)](http://jsfiddle.net/Panman8201/MKZrm/10/) with a working example. Key pieces are:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- child of the body tag -->
<span id="top-link-block" class="hidden">
    <a href="#top" class="well well-sm" onclick="$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow');return false;">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> Back to Top
    </a>
</span><!-- /top-link-block -->
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
// Only enable if the document has a long scroll bar
// Note the window height + offset
if ( ($(window).height() + 100) < $(document).height() ) {
    $('#top-link-block').removeClass('hidden').affix({
        // how far to scroll down before link "slides" into view
        offset: {top:100}
    });
}
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
#top-link-block.affix-top {
    position: absolute; /* allows it to "slide" up into view */
    bottom: -82px;
    left: 10px;
}
#top-link-block.affix {
    position: fixed; /* keeps it on the bottom once in view */
    bottom: 18px;
    left: 10px;
}
</style>
```

***Note:** I was not able to use the [affix bottom offset (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/Panman8201/MKZrm/8/) to hide the link for short pages due to a bug with affix container height calculation (Bootstrap Issue # 4647). I'm sure there is a workaround and would welcome the solution to this method.*

Comment: Does this `($('body').outerHeight() > $(window).height())` not work instead of `( ($(window).height() + 100) < $(document).height() )` ?

Comment: The point of adding the offset difference was to not enable the Affix component if the user would never reach it. Couple things I'm not clear on are; document vs 'body' and height() vs outerHeight() when used on document.

Comment: I was slightly wrong in using body you could just use `$(document).height();` but I understand your need now. document is the rendered page whereas body is just the body element (html element could have padding or a fixed height, this wouldn't affect body height). height() is the elements height (depending on box method) which may or may not include padding, whereas outer height includes padding, border and can include margin https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So the height comparison that I'm doing will work just fine?

Comment: Yep it will, if you want to get clever with it you can change the 100 to the size of the affix icon dynamically just in case you ever change it

Comment: how to move it `back to top` to right side of bottom page ?

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the back to top button, proved useful for me as well :)
one minor improvement though would be to avoid using the `onclick=""` on the `<a>` tag but instead using `jQuery's` event registrator:

HTML:

```
...
<a href="#top" id ="backToTopBtn" class="well well-sm">
...
```

JS:

```
 $('#backToTopBtn').click(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow');return false;
    });
```

Comment: Good point, that certainly would be a better way to go. I just stuck it in the onclick="" to keep the example shorter and less complicated. Thanks!