# Unable to add "Move to the top" button via Ruby on Rails and Twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add popup "Move to the top" button in the left bottom corner of the page via Ruby on Rails and Twitter bootstrap.

I've add the following code (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413203/bootstrap-affix-back-to-top-link) thread):

**application.html.erb (in the head section)**

```
<script>
// Only enable if the document has a long scroll bar
// Note the window height + offset
if ( ($(window).height() + 100) < $(document).height() ) {
    $('#top-link-block').removeClass('hidden').affix({
        // how far to scroll down before link "slides" into view
        offset: {top:100}
    });
}
</script>
```

**welcome\index.html.erb**

```
<span id="top-link-block" class="hidden">
    <a href="#top" class="well well-sm" onclick="$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow');return false;">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> Back to Top
    </a>
</span>
```

**welcome.css.css**

```
#top-link-block.affix-top {
  position: absolute; /* allows it to "slide" up into view */
  bottom: -82px;
  left: 10px;
}
#top-link-block.affix {
  position: fixed; /* keeps it on the bottom once in view */
  bottom: 18px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

It gives me no result -- there is no popup button and any visual effects at all.

I've add the alert messages to the javascript:

```
<script>
    alert('1');
    $('#top-link-block').removeClass('hidden').affix({
        offset: {top:100}
    });
    alert('2')
</script>
```

It gives me "1" but there is no alert box with "2".

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I add such button to the page?

btw I'm using twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8 and Ruby on Rails 4.1.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript bails out if it encounters an error, so your lack of a second alert suggests that there was a problem with that script. Check your browser's console for details. My guess is you'll see "undefined is not a function", meaning that `.affix` isn't defined anywhere. It's not a standard part of jQuery.